# securityd using 100% CPU and polluting system.log

Tags: macos

Since I upgraded to Mavericks, I often have the following processes using full CPU power:

- `securityd`
- `syslogd`
- `kernel_task`

I guess `securityd` contains a bug, because it is polluting `/var/log/system.log` with thousands of messages per second, and the system can not follow up.

Here is an example of messages I get:

```
Nov 11 15:55:10 localhost securityd[22]: assertion failed: 13A603: libxpc.dylib + 44365 [4554927A-9467-365C-91F1-5A116989DD7F]: 0x13
Nov 11 16:14:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Nov 11 15:55:10 localhost securityd[22]: assertion failed: 13A603: libxpc.dylib + 26642 [4554927A-9467-365C-91F1-5A116989DD7F]: 0x13
Nov 11 16:14:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Nov 11 15:55:10 localhost securityd[22]: assertion failed: 13A603: libxpc.dylib + 44365 [4554927A-9467-365C-91F1-5A116989DD7F]: 0x13
Nov 11 16:14:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Nov 11 15:55:10 localhost securityd[22]: assertion failed: 13A603: libxpc.dylib + 26642 [4554927A-9467-365C-91F1-5A116989DD7F]: 0x13
Nov 11 16:14:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

I believe this is a critical issue, as it makes Mac OS X is extremely slow and unresponsive.

Killing `securityid` doesn't help. The process is recreated, and keeps polluting `syslogd`.

If I reboot the entire system, everything seems ok for a while, before the same issue happens again. I didn't figured out what triggers this issue yet.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer, you could run `sudo sysdiagnose securityd` and [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) and possibly get assistance from apple in fixing the bug or troubleshooting the cause.

Comment: You could also try to temporarily remove `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.securityd.plist` or `/usr/sbin/securityd` or [do an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).

Comment: I've had this securityd assertion failed problem with 10.9, too. I'm not sure what the problem is yet, but I've rebooted in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455) and been uninstalling various third-party packages (virus scanner, ...) with kernel extensions as identified by [EtreCheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck). I suspect that one of them is the problem, but since it is a bit intermittent, I'm going to wait a while longer before I claim to have fixed it.

Answer (score 59):

I have the same problem with `securityd` occupying high CPU on a Mac, it's caused by Source Tree credentials in Keychain Access. Removing the login data of SourceTree in KeyChain restored my CPU usage back to normal levels.

Comment: happened to me today. Immediately restored once i removed those

Comment: How to remove the login data of SourceTree in KeyChain?
I guess mine high CPU caused by SourceTree installation today too.
I restart the machine and solved the problem.

Comment: same problem... I have removed the login from keychain and changed the sourcetree remotes to ssh ones

Comment: Stupid SourceTree asks for these credentials in a loop (I know because if you don't click "Allow always", it will never stop asking).

Comment: It does stop after 3 times of denying it for me.

Comment: SourceTree spawns several ssh process in a loop. Killing the ssh process from the Activity Monitor solves the problem. But if you still have SourceTree running, then it will respawn the ssh process again and eating the CPU (again).

Comment: Wow! How did you figure this out? It would never have occurred to me

Comment: 3 years later and this is still happening

Comment: Bye bye atlassian.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the haywire securityd process was caused by GitHub desktop app - during commit, network issues caused an error in ssh handshake. Subsequent commits went fine. GitHub app was left open, securityd was heating up my CPU. Quitting GitHub app fixed the problem - probably terminating something in securityd. So my guess is, securityd has some infinite loop issue during crypto operations, maybe just with ssh and handshakes.

So, check if and how your daily workflow can trigger securityd (logging into server? github?) and isolate the problem.

Comment: Github app was the culprit for me as well.

Comment: Seeing this, I think SourceTree is the culprit for me. Quitting SourceTree doesn't fix the problem, but starting SourceTree does seem to start it. And there do seem to be SSH handshake issues involved. I will try to address those and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily alleviate the problem by restarting SecurityAgent using the following terminal command:

```
sudo killall SecurityAgent
```

This worked each time for me. I am still investigating the root cause.

---

As far as I can tell, this was triggered by switching to another user account where I'd had to reset the password as I'd forgotten the original password. This caused multiple Keychain failures (original password required to unlock the Keychain) and I got an 'endless loop' of prompts along the lines of 'Apple Messages Agent wants to use the item 'login' from your keychain..'

Comment: I also have multiple prompts about my password after a login (2, 3, maybe 4 from time to time).

Comment: Killing SecurityAgent seems to have worked for me as well. Thanks! But I'd like to understand the root cause as well. I've just filled bug #15924434 at https://bugreport.apple.com/ with the output of sysdiagnose securityd.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same exact problem for the second time in a row within a week with the exact same messages in the console.

For me, rebooting usually solves the problem (first time I had to force shutdown as machine was unresponsive). And like you, I have yet to find the trigger that starts the messages.

The activity monitor is not the culprit, I am usually alerted by the fan going crazy, so then I start the activity monitor just to see both syslogd and securityd using about 90% of CPU.

Comment: Might the trigger be opening Activity Monitor and asking it to graph historical energy usage patterns? I see the spike in CPU usage when I do that, but apparently my logs from the past day or two aren't corrupt in a way that causes the flood of console messages.

Comment: @bmike no. It seems like nothing special triggers it. My feeling is that it happens when computer is on for a while, and when I login after a screen saver / suspended activity. Also, when I login, I have two or three other prompts about my password, it may be related to this issue.

Comment: I filled a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/ and it was closed today, saying it is a duplicate of bug #15090630 (that is still open). Is there a way to see this bug report?

Comment: Restart the computer worked for me too. Thanks.
My securityd high CPU was with SourceTree installation.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting the actual cause may be problematic since [XPC is a generic inter-process communication protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/xpcservice.plist.5.html) and only loads on demand. The Apple software uses this subsystem as can any third party program - so it could be Apple's fault or it could be something you are running and the main problem is you don't have an easy way to know which program is causing the heavy logging load (and perhaps a heavy legitimate workload as well as just logging).

---

I agree that any diagnostic logging that is so rapid and uncontrollable as to affect either the energy usage of the computer or the performance of the computer noticeably should be considered a fault.

The most productive way to address that is actually to document the problem and report this as a bug to Apple.

Mavericks has done a stellar job at exposing both the diagnostic tools and the energy usage over time of all processes to the interested end user.

- Open Energy Saver, select Energy and sort by Avg Energy Impact -  snap a picture of the window it processes the last day's usage logs.
- Select the CPU view, search for `securityd`, select it in the list of active tasks and then "Run System Diagnostics..." either from the View menu or the gear in the toolbar.
- Send both the picture and the compressed diagnostics report to Apple at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

You will need an AppleID that is associated with some sort of developer account, so you can sign up as a Safari developer for free if you don't already have an account that is enabled for reporting specific bugs to Apple.

Comment: Also - if anyone has steps to reproduce this bug in securityd - I'll happily file a duplicate bug report and do the work to submit this to Apple, but I've not had a single system log any volume of these messages on 10.9 for several months.

Comment: thanks for the instructions, I generated a report, but your link where I could send the report doesn't work. It redirect to a JSON dataset, saying "Your session has timed out due to inactivity."

Comment: Looks like the URL has changed, I'll link to the article that explains how to use the tool instead. It has a sign in and sign up link on the left of the page (currently).

Comment: It finally works — thanks — maybe it was a temporary bug on Apple's servers. I filled a bug with the output of sysdiagnose securityd.

Answer (score 1):

I created a VM using virtualBox and this issue is somewhat recreateable.  I have created some keychain items and when I visit the website that the keychain item is for, the VM hangs for a good 1-2min, then frees up.  It may be git-osxkeychain-helper causing the securityd process to eat the whole cpu.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by following:

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Force quit **securityd**
3. Enter the password of ssh key like the image
4. **Uncheck Store password in keychain**
5. Click Ok

Hope to help you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug much older than Mavericks. I'm not sure I was having the same problem as you because I never checked my `syslog`, but I did have `securityd` eating up CPU and RAM. I used [an old solution from 2007](http://www.43folders.com/2007/01/22/securityd-keychain-fix) (for Leopard?).

**tldr:**

`sudo mv /var/db/CodeEquivalenceDatabase /var/db/CodeEquivalenceDatabase.old`

then restart. Feel free to delete the old file afterwards, as OS X automatically creates a new one.

Comment: Hello, please be aware that this bug is related to the system logs pollution. If securityd didn't produce so much debug output, the system wouldn't run at 100% CPU. Apparently, Apple developers are aware of this bug, because I reported it and it was marked as a duplicate. So I guess we have to wait…

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have something to do with keychain manager. I was just having this and killed keychain and it went away.

Comment: How to kill keychain?